# organizar listas

Tags: html, css, grid

Esperando se encuentren muy bien, escribo acá para consultar un par de cositas, estoy en un bootcamp de desarrollo web y no logro meter la grilla dentro de la pagina, se que se puede hacer algún tipo de slider para continuar viendo los productos, pero ni idea como hacerlo, ya me he calentado la cabeza un rato y quise ver si me podían ayudar a lograrlo, también quería saber como hacer para escoger los colores, y que tipos de fuente recomiendan usar, muchas gracias por su tiempo ¡no hay preguntas estúpidas, sino estúpidos que no preguntan!

[image: se muestra la tabla fuera de la pagina]

mi codigo:

```css
.grilla{
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 2;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(50px,auto);
/** visibility: hidden; **/
  
}
.uno {
    text-align: center;
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 1;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    border-radius: 15px; 
    box-shadow: 5px 10px 8px rgb(26, 5, 5);
    font-family: monospace;
    margin: auto;
}

.dos {
    text-align: center;
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 1;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    border-radius: 15px; 
    box-shadow: 5px 10px 8px black;
    font-family: monospace;
    margin: auto;

}

.tres {
    text-align: center;
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 2;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    border-radius: 15px; 
    box-shadow: 5px 10px 8px black;
    font-family: monospace;
    margin: auto;
}

.cuatro {
    text-align: center;
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 2;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    border-radius: 15px; 
    box-shadow: 5px 10px 8px black;
    font-family: monospace;
    margin: auto;
}
.cinco {
    text-align: center;
    grid-column: 3;
    grid-row: 2;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    border-radius: 15px; 
    box-shadow: 5px 10px 8px black;
    font-family: monospace;
    margin: auto;
}
.seis {
    text-align: center;
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 3;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    border-radius: 15px; 
    box-shadow: 5px 10px 8px black;
    font-family: monospace;
    margin: auto;
}

.siete{
    text-align: center;
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 3;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    border-radius: 15px; 
    box-shadow: 5px 10px 8px black;
    font-family: monospace;
    margin: auto;
}
.ocho{
    text-align: center;
    grid-column: 3;
    grid-row: 3;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    border-radius: 15px; 
    box-shadow: 5px 10px 8px black;
    font-family: monospace;
    margin: auto;
}
.nueve{
    text-align: center;
    grid-column: 3;
    grid-row: 1;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    border-radius: 15px; 
    box-shadow: 5px 10px 8px black;
    font-family: monospace;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<h1 style="margin-top: 10%;">Productos</h1>
        <!-- insertamos la grilla -->
        <div style="margin-top: 10%;" class="grilla">
            <div class="uno">
                <br>
                <h1> HP<br>
                     625LA </h1>
                <img src="img/1.jpg">
                <p>
                    <br>
                    <br>    
                    Procesador Intel I3 9900K <br>
                    16GB Ram y 250GB SSD<br>
                    T.video rtx 2060M<br>
                    Windows 10 lte </p><br>
                <p> $1.500.000</p>  <br>
                <i class="fa-solid fa-basket-shopping"></i><input type="submit" id="agreP" value="Agregar al carrito"><br><br>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="dos">
                <br>
                <h1> Asus gl752 </h1>
                <img src="img/2.jpg">
                <p>
                    <br>
                    Procesador Intel i9 9900K <br>
                    16GB Ram y 250GB SSD<br>
                    T.video rtx 2090M<br>
                    Windows 11 pro 
                </p>
                <br>
                <p> $2.500.000</p>
                <br>
                <i class="fa-solid fa-basket-shopping"></i><input type="submit" id="agreP" value="Agregar al carrito"><br><br>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="tres">
                <br>
                <h1>Asus XT16</h1>
                <img src="img/1.jpg">
                <p>
                    <br>
                    Procesador Intel I9 9990K <br>
                    32GB Ram y 10TB SSD<br>
                    T.video rtx 3080ti<br>
                    Windows 11 pro.</p><br>
                <p> $6.500.000</p><br>
                <i class="fa-solid fa-basket-shopping"></i><input type="submit" id="agreP" value="Agregar al carrito"><br><br>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="cuatro">
                <br>
                <h1> LG 778 </h1>
                <img src="img/1.jpg">
                <p>
                    <br>
                    Procesador Qualcomm 7850+<br>
                    8GB Ram. 256gb memoria interna<br>
                    Pantalla 4k con infinity display +<br>
                    android 13.4
                </p>
                <br>
                <p> $800.000</p>
                <br>
                <i class="fa-solid fa-basket-shopping"></i><input type="submit" id="agreP" value="Agregar al carrito"><br><br>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="cinco">
                <br>
                <h1> HP 625LA </h1>
                <img src="img/1.jpg">
                <p>
                    <br>
                    Procesador Intel I3 9900K <br>
                    16GB Ram y 250GB SSD<br>
                    T.video rtx 2060M<br>
                    Windows 10 lte 
                </p>
                <br>
                <p> $1.500.000</p>
                <br>
                <i class="fa-solid fa-basket-shopping"></i><input type="submit" id="agreP" value="Agregar al carrito"><br><br>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="seis">
                <br>
                <h1> HP 625LA </h1>
                <img src="img/1.jpg">
                <p>
                    <br>
                    Procesador Intel I3 9900K <br>
                    16GB Ram y 250GB SSD<br>
                    T.video rtx 2060M<br>
                    Windows 10 lte 
                </p>
                <br>
                <p> $1.500.000</p>
                <br>
                <i class="fa-solid fa-basket-shopping"></i><input type="submit" id="agreP" value="Agregar al carrito"><br><br>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="siete">
                <br>
                <h1> HP 625LA </h1>
                <img src="img/1.jpg">
                <p>
                    <br>
                    Procesador Intel I3 9900K <br>
                    16GB Ram y 250GB SSD<br>
                    T.video rtx 2060M<br>
                    Windows 10 lte 
                </p>
                <br>
                <p> $1.500.000</p>
                <br>
                <i class="fa-solid fa-basket-shopping"></i><input type="submit" id="agreP" value="Agregar al carrito"><br><br>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="ocho">
                <br>
                <h1> HP 625LA </h1>
                <img src="img/1.jpg">
                <p>
                    <br>
                    Procesador Intel I3 9900K <br>
                    16GB Ram y 250GB SSD<br>
                    T.video rtx 2060M<br>
                    Windows 10 lte 
                </p>
                <br>
                <p> $1.500.000</p>
                <br>
                <i class="fa-solid fa-basket-shopping"></i><input type="submit" id="agreP" value="Agregar al carrito"><br><br>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="nueve">
                <br>
                <h1> HP 625LA </h1>
                <img src="img/1.jpg">
                <p>
                    <br>
                    Procesador Intel I3 9900K <br>
                    16GB Ram y 250GB SSD<br>
                    T.video rtx 2060M<br>
                    Windows 10 lte 
                </p>
                <br>
                <p> $1.500.000</p>
                <br>
                <i class="fa-solid fa-basket-shopping"></i><input type="submit" id="agreP" value="Agregar al carrito"><br><br>
            </div>
        </div>
        

        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes añadir al contenedor (.grilla) la propiedad **overflow:auto** para visualizarlo con una especie de slider (a través de la barra de desplazamiento del propio contenedor y no de la página):

```
.grilla {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

O también añadiendo la propiedad **flex-wrap: wrap**, que permite desplazar hacia abajo el resto de las cajas que por su tamaño no pueden ubicarse en el lado de otra:

```
.grilla {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```